# Does autowiring work for classes instantiated from PerConnectionWebSocketHandler?

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration-files, autowired, spring-java-config

I can successfully read an autowired instance of HandlerSettings in the main class, so I know I have the application.properties entries correct.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="handler")
public class HandlerSettings {
    private int timeout;

    public int getTimeout(){
        return timeout;
    }

    public void setTimeout(int timeout){
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }
}
```

I am having difficulties trying to autowire fields in the MyHandler class, which is instantiated within a PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableConfigurationProperties(HandlerSettings.class)
public class MyController implements WebSocketConfigurer{
    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
        return new PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(MyHandler.class));
    }
```

I want to autowire fields in an abstract base class of MyHandler.

```
@Component
public abstract class Handler implements WebSocketHandler {
    @Autowired
    private HandlerSettings handlerSettings;
    ...
}
```

MyHandler inherits from Handler:

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler
```

The example in the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) does not address what to do in either the case of inheritance, or the way classes are instantiated with the PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.

I have tried unsuccessfully to autowire fields in Handler. It is possible to autowire if the class is instantiated by PerConnectionWebSocketHandler? If so, is there something special I have to do to autowire the base class, but not the classes that extend it?

Answer (score 1):

As per the Source Codes unless you set the `PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.setBeanFactory` in will instantiate a Handler without the Injected Beans.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableConfigurationProperties(HandlerSettings.class)
public class MyController implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
        PerConnectionWebSocketHandler perConnectionWebSocketHandler = new PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(MyHandler.class);
        perConnectionWebSocketHandler.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        return perConnectionWebSocketHandler;
    }
}
```

Comment: This change is not sufficient to get the HandlerSettings configured in application.properties in MyHandler.

Comment: Worked for me, Autowiring beans in my handler class works as expected